# Project Management Tools?

Tags: web-development, project-management, tasks

I'm looking for a better PM tool.  Something like http://www.axosoft.com/ontime where it looks more like a e-mail client but preferably web hosted.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/91310/project-management-tools-like-basecamp-that-integrate-with-salesforce/184955#184955 - Check my answer there. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**FogBugz**

- http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/
- free for two people

more information at SO tag [project-management]

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management

Answer (score 1):

[Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) is a web based project management tool. They have a free version that is limited to one project and you cannot upload files.

[Here](https://signup.37signals.com/basecamp/Free/signup/new?source=basecamphq.com&__utma=1.3100535970415599000.1251114577.1251114577.1251116479.2&__utmb=1.12.10.1251116479&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1251114577.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29|utmccn=%28direct%29|utmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=88235931) is a direct link to the free version since people have problems looking for it.

Comment: Free trial ≠ Free.

Comment: There is a free version, but it is limited to the number of projects.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Teamlab](http://www.teamlab.com), a free, web-based solution for PM.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend either

PHProject (www.phprojekt.com)
or 
Trac (trac.edgewall.org).

Both are free and open source.

You can also build up your own pm-suite with custom tooling (e.g. mantis as bugtracker, svn as version control, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

How about [ClockingIT](http://www.clockingit.com)? It's free and you can host it yourself or use their own servers.

Answer (score 0):

We use TeamLab - easy to navigate and offer just all the needed features. In addition, they have just integrated the possibility to edit the documentation online.

Of course, there are some minuses (like anywhere), this platform doesn't have CRM and calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Feng Office](http://www.fengoffice.com/).

They provide three variants (compared [here](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/compare.php)):

- [Feng Sky](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/moreinfo-sky.php) if you want no job with hosting etc. Sign up and use it
- [Feng Onsite](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/moreinfo-onsite.php) if you want to install it on your servers but have the guys of Feng Office to upgrade, customize, etc. the installation
- [Feng Community](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/moreinfo-community.php) if you want the **free solution**: Feng Office is **open source**, so you could download the installation ([here](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/community/downloads.php)) and install it to your webspace.

Functionality is similar to [PHProjekt](http://www.phprojekt.com/), which was recommended by [t0mt0m](https://superuser.com/questions/28602/project-management-tools/28677#28677).