# Time planning software

Tags: calendar, project-management, time-management

I'm looking for some time planning software. I have simple but specific needs. I'd like to be able to track and plan work for about 10 people. They do certain type of task working on a couple of projects at the same time. So I need something that works like a calendar that shows data "per project" or "per person".Using of standard web calendars didn't work (I can have a calendar for a person, but not for project at the same time). I've looked at different software for that but most of the time they are over bloated (tracking bugs, uploading files, doing accounting etc). In a perfect world I'd need something that:

- web based but installed locally
- works as interactive calendar/gannt chart (AJAX style ability do resize task length)
- allows tasks linking (one task requires other task to be completed)
- allows to see what task are happening: globally, per project, per person
- is not bloated
- is opensource (or not very expensive)

Thanks for any clues on that topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Planning Tools](http://superuser.com/questions/40787/project-planning-tools) and http://superuser.com/questions/94821/project-management-timesheet-and-planning-software and http://superuser.com/questions/28602/project-management-tools .

Comment: it similar but not a duplicate, as I'm looking for a simple resource management than bloated IT project management suites.
I found something that almost suits my needs (except price  - 500 Euro per license) planningPME.